# Unable to download Android SDK programatically for API level > 13

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-2.3

I want to download the Android SDK automatically because my target audience is not supposed to be tech savvy crowd.
I parse this xml to get the android sdk related info - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml

The `sdk:url` tag is supposed to contain the url of the Android SDK zip. 
However, for API level 14 and above it doesn't contain the url of the zip but the name of the zip only.

Is there any reliable way to download the Android SDK zip file for API 14 and above ?